# Proving $\phi$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

In [this video](https://youtu.be/1wyOoLUjUeI?t=5344) the lecturer gave an example, that is:

> $\phi : M\to N$, where $M$ is equipped with arbitrary topology $\mathcal O_M$, and $N$ is equipped with the chaotic topology $\{\varnothing, N\}$. Then any $\phi$ is continuous.

It's clear that the preimage of $\varnothing$ must be $\varnothing$ and thus a open set in $M$, but why the preimage of $N$ is an open set in $M$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preimage $\phi^{-1}(N) = \{x \in M : \phi(x) \in N\}$ is equal to $M$ and $M$ is open by definition of a topology.

Comment: Ohhh, thanks a lot. Now it is clear. :D